# Why are alcohols considered slightly basic (based on pKa values)?

Tags: acid-base

I understand why it makes sense for an alcohol to be slightly basic given the hydroxyl group and the electron-donating properties of the alkyl chain. But I'm a bit confused as to why it's the case based on the pKa of ROH and of ROH2+. pKa of ROH is approx. 16, meaning half of the alcohol would be deprotonated to become RO- at pH 16, while the pKa of ROH2+ is approx. -3, meaning half of the alcohol would accept an extra proton to become ROH2+ at pH -3. A pH of 16 is much less extreme than a pH of -3, so doesn't alcohol more readily give up a proton than accept an extra one, if one were to look only at the pKa values?

Comment: Alcohols are not slightly basic. They are about as basic as water (which means: not much at all), only less. Also, they are about as acidic as water, only less. Taken together, this reads: neutral.

Comment: A  pKa of 16 means equal concentrations of alkoxide and alkonium ions of about 10^-8. Please explain the pKa of ROH2+.

Comment: @jimchmst at pH = pKa for ROH, [RO-]/[ROH] = 1, and at pH = pKa for ROH2+, [ROH]/[ROH2+] = 1 (I'm a bit confused to as to why you're saying RO- and ROH2+ would be equal)

Answer (score 2):

Alcohols especially methanol and ethanol self-protonate as does water. There are kinetic differences, superdry alcohols have a sharp OH NMR peak that couples to the adjacent carbon H's; the coupling vanishes with a trace of water. The equation is similar to water: 2R-OH = R-OH2+ + RO-. Alcohols are Bronsted acids and bases in equal amounts.
Alcohols do not furnish OH- ions so they are not Arrhenius bases. [The hydroxyl group is not the hydroxide ion.]  In many organic reactions alcohols react as Lewis bases but not as Lewis acids so maybe this is the reason for the idea. Potentiometric titrations in ethanol-water are very similar to just water and my limited experience with the pH of ethanol-water mixes is that they are effectively neutral to slightly acidic from CO2 absorption.

Here is one article to confuse the issue: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8201227/ This indicates that at low concentrations in water alcohols are acidic but pure water extrapolates to an acidic pH so CO2 may be involved. At high concentrations the solutions are basic. This could possibly be caused by the lowering of the water chemical activity and not the basicity of the alcohols.